# how to customize image button in android

Tags: java, android

i am new in android development , it very difficult to design customized user interface in

android . i have a image button that have default shap is ractangle i need do it as

rounded

shap please help me .

```
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"

android:layout_width="match_parent"

android:layout_height="match_parent"

android:background="#82B210"

android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"

android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"

android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"

android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"

tools:context=".SettingActivity" >



<ImageButton

    android:id="@+id/imageButton1"

    android:layout_width="wrap_content"

    android:layout_height="wrap_content"

    android:src="@drawable/makeconfess" />



<TextView

    android:id="@+id/textView1"

    android:layout_width="wrap_content"

    android:layout_height="wrap_content"

    android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/imageButton1"

    android:layout_alignRight="@+id/imageButton1"

    android:layout_below="@+id/imageButton1"

    android:layout_marginTop="27dp"

    android:text="  Make a\nConfess"

    android:textColor="#FFFFFF"

    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium" />
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To create a circle shape of button firstly you have to create an xml in drawable folder

circle_shape_drawable.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" 
    android:shape="oval">
    <solid 
       android:color="#666666"/>
   <size 
       android:width="120dp"
        android:height="120dp"/>
</shape>
```

use this xml in button background as

```
<Button
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="@drawable/circle_shape_drawable"
        android:text="@string/hello_world" />
```

Comment: i want to add a background image how to do it ??

Comment: You want circular image as background on rectangle button?

Answer (score 0):

xml to create a button in Android

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Button"
        android:background="@drawable/one" />    

<! --  android:background property is  used to apply background to a to button. And @drawable/one means there is a image name as one in your drawable folder we are applying it as background to this button. -->

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button2"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Button" />

</LinearLayout>
```

**Code to define rounded corner button**

```
<? xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:shape="rectangle">   //Defines the shape of button you wants
    <solid android:color="#eeffff"/>
    <corners android:bottomLeftRadius="8dp"  //how much curve you want from bottom left corner
             android:bottomRightRadius="8dp"//how much curve you want from bottom right corner
             android:topLeftRadius="8dp""//how much curve you want from top left corner
             android:topRightRadius="8dp"/> "//how much curve you want from top right corner

</shape>
```

default shape of button is rectangle so now I will tell you how to create round button

For that you again need to create an xml file in your drawable folder, and name it as button_shape.xml

The codes for button_shape.xml are as follows:

**Code to define button shapes**

```
<? xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<shape 
    xmlns:android=http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android  android:shape="oval" > 
    //There are many other shapes also available they are rectangle,ring,line and oval
    <solid android:color="#ffcccc"/> //applying the colour to the button.
    <stroke android:width="2dp"
            android:color="#ffffff"/>

</shape>
```

Comment: i need shap of button is rounded or circle not Rectangle so what should i do ??

Comment: Hope you get what you desired :)

Answer (score 0):

You can define a `Button` or `ImageButton` with a xml file and save it into the `drawable` folder. In this way you can provide different states for your button (pressed, focused, normal, ...).

For example:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector
  xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item android:state_pressed="true" android:drawable="@drawable/btn_action_hover" />
    <item android:state_selected="true" android:drawable="@drawable/btn_action_hover" />
    <item android:state_focused="true" android:drawable="@drawable/btn_action_hover" />
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/btn_action_normal" />
</selector>
```

To be sure your button will be displayed correctly on any resolution/screen size, I would suggest to use 9 patch drawables as explained in http://developer.android.com/tools/help/draw9patch.html.

Answer (score 0):

in the drawable folder in the res folder

Create a android xml file and named as cbutton.xml

Then enter the bellow code

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?> 
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" > 
    <item android:state_pressed="true" 
          android:drawable="@drawable/pressselected">
    </item> 
    <item android:state_focused="true" 
          android:drawable="@drawable/presshighlight"> 
    </item> 
    <item  android:drawable="@drawable/press"></item> 
</selector>
```

Then set this file as background of your `ImageButton` like in below.

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android = http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android 
android:layout_width="fill_parent" 
android:layout_height="fill_parent" 
android:orientation="vertical" >

<TextView 
android:id="@+id/textView1" 
android:layout_width="wrap_content" 
android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
android:layout_gravity="center" 
android:layout_marginTop="10dp" 
android:text="Click to view Custom Button Action" 
android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium" />

<Button 
android:id="@+id/button1" 
android:layout_width="wrap_content" 
android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
android:background="@drawable/press" 
android:layout_gravity="center" 
android:layout_marginTop="30dp" 
/>

   </LinearLayout>
```